Removing and replacing broken wheels on a Subaru PowerStroke EA190V Pressure Washer
PS. I just edited my post to include two close-up pics of the bolts.
So, I discovered a bunch of heavy stuff fell on my pressure washer, and both wheels broke (please see picture.)

I've been looking for instructions on how to remove the wheels (or whatever remains that are still attached to the axel) as well as finding replacements parts.
But I don't have much luck in finding any information.
I hope someone might have experience with these. Thanks.
PS. This is the top view of the bolt. It doesn't show any threading or way to unscrew or remove it off the axle.

The next picture is from the bottom side of the axle, opposite the head of the bolt.

I think most 12" wheels will do fine as a replacement, but I don't see a way to remove the bolts to remove the wheels, not unless I have to cut their heads off.
I just want to make sure that's the way to go.

A close-up pic of the end of the axle/bolt might be useful.

Would need a better picture of the black centre bolt/thingamajig, but removing that will help.  For the wheel/s, look around for little kids bikes/strollers.

Or spare lawnmower wheels, I've seen those for sale before

golf cart wheels perhaps (the kind you push or pull, not the kind you ride)

cut some circles out of plywood

@crip659 I'm wondering if that's not a bolt and simply a press-fit cap on an axle rod.  (The requested pic would hopefully clarify, of course!)

Hi, I just updated my post with pics showing the bolt. @crip659, yes, I didn't know how to call those in English (press-fit caps), but yes, that's what they look like to be.

A small pry bar/big screwdriver should remove them.  Might have to lift a bit and turn, lift new section and turn.  If that does not work, cut, drill a hole in the axle for a cotter pin and pack with washers between the pin and wheel.

One Small Victory! Pry the top with a small pry bar, wear gloves it a knuckle buster (not much ledge to pray against on the cap). Now your cap is almost off on top, on the bottom where it was to begin with.  Take two narrow ended tapered drift punches and hammer them down on each side of the axle, so they stick out below the bottom side edges of the cap. They will fit tightly and then take a medium pry bar and pry against the body of your punches...voila.  You just made the punches something to pry against!  Put on the new wheel and use the hammer to put the cap back on.  Do a victory dance!  BTW Drift Punch is also called Pin Punch.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
